# Callback function in JSONP jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, wordpress, opera

I am using some jQuery scripts to get a JSON feed from Flickr and YouTube and generate the HTML from them on my WordPress site
For Flickr I use

```
<!-- Script to grab photos from Flickr feed -->
<script type="text/javascript">
// Set variables needed for query
var URL = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne";
var ID = "<?php echo get_option('of_flickrid') ?>";
var jsonFormat = "&lang=en-us&format=json&jsoncallback=?";

var ajaxURL = URL + "?id=" + ID + jsonFormat;
// Get the last photos of the flickr account, parse it into HTML code
$.getJSON(ajaxURL, function(data){
     var htmlString = "<h1><?php echo get_option('of_photostext') ?></h1>";

    // Now start cycling through our array of Flickr photo details
    $.each(data.items, function(i,item){

        // I only want the ickle square thumbnails
     var sourceSquare = (item.media.m).replace("_m.jpg", "_s.jpg");

        // Here's where we piece together the HTML
        htmlString += '<a href="' + item.link + '" target="_blank">';
        htmlString += '<img title="' + item.title + '" src="' + sourceSquare;
        htmlString += '" alt="'; htmlString += item.title + '" class="rounded"/>';
        htmlString += '</a>';
        if(i === 11){
            return false;
        }
    });

    // Pop our HTML in the #images DIV
    $('#photos').html(htmlString);

}); // End getJSOON
</script>
<!-- End of Script to grab photos from Flickr feed -->
```

and for YouTube:

```
<!-- Script to grab videos from YouTube feed -->
<script type="text/javascript">
// Set variables needed for query
var URL = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/";
var UserName = "<?php echo get_option('of_youtubeid') ?>";
var jsonFormat = "/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc&max-results=2&jsoncallback=?";
// Construct the JSON feed of the YouTube user's channel
var ajaxURL = URL + UserName + jsonFormat;
// Get the last videos of the YouTube account, parse it into HTML code
$.getJSON(ajaxURL, function(data){
     var htmlString = "<h1><?php echo get_option('of_videostext') ?></h1>";

    $.each(data.data.items, function(i,item){       
        // Here's where we piece together the HTML
        htmlString += '<iframe class="videos" type="text/html" width="640" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/';
        htmlString += item.id;
        htmlString += '?autoplay=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
    });

    // Pop our HTML in the #videos DIV
    $('#videos').html(htmlString);
});
</script>
<!-- End of Script to grab videos from YouTube feed -->
```

The scripts are running pretty well in all browsers except Opera.

When I remove the callback function from YouTube JSON link, it works on Opera but stops on IE and vice versa.. What in the world might be going on?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to append the query string to your URL for jQuery AJAX calls.  Use the data parameter [described in the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).  Here's an example:

```
$.getJSON('myURL.php', { param1: value1, param2: value2 }, function(data) {
    //handle my data here
    alert(data);
});
```

For your situation I'd try the following code for Flickr:

```
<!-- Script to grab photos from Flickr feed -->
<script type="text/javascript">
// Set variables needed for query
var URL = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne";
var ID = "<?php echo get_option('of_flickrid') ?>";

// Get the last photos of the flickr account, parse it into HTML code
$.getJSON(URL + "?id=" + ID, { lang: 'en-us', format: 'json', jsoncallback: '?' } function(data){
     var htmlString = "<h1><?php echo get_option('of_photostext') ?></h1>";

    // Now start cycling through our array of Flickr photo details
    $.each(data.items, function(i,item){

        // I only want the ickle square thumbnails
     var sourceSquare = (item.media.m).replace("_m.jpg", "_s.jpg");

        // Here's where we piece together the HTML
        htmlString += '<a href="' + item.link + '" target="_blank">';
        htmlString += '<img title="' + item.title + '" src="' + sourceSquare;
        htmlString += '" alt="'; htmlString += item.title + '" class="rounded"/>';
        htmlString += '</a>';
        if(i === 11){
            return false;
        }
    });

    // Pop our HTML in the #images DIV
    $('#photos').html(htmlString);

}); // End getJSOON
</script>
<!-- End of Script to grab photos from Flickr feed -->
```

And for YouTube:

```
<!-- Script to grab videos from YouTube feed -->
<script type="text/javascript">
// Set variables needed for query
var URL = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/";
var UserName = "<?php echo get_option('of_youtubeid') ?>";

// Get the last videos of the YouTube account, parse it into HTML code
$.getJSON(URL + UserName + "/uploads", { v: 2, alt: 'jsonc', max-results: 2, jsoncallback: '?' } function(data){
     var htmlString = "<h1><?php echo get_option('of_videostext') ?></h1>";

    $.each(data.data.items, function(i,item){       
        // Here's where we piece together the HTML
        htmlString += '<iframe class="videos" type="text/html" width="640" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/';
        htmlString += item.id;
        htmlString += '?autoplay=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
    });

    // Pop our HTML in the #videos DIV
    $('#videos').html(htmlString);
});
</script>
<!-- End of Script to grab videos from YouTube feed -->
```

Comment: Here's the deal @hamama: something tells me that if your code doesn't work in only one browser then you've got a greater issue here.  All browsers process code in relatively the same way, for something which works everywhere but one place tells me that something else you've coded is making Opera freak out.

Comment: Not to mention, I don't have all of your code, so it's tough to understand the context.  You're going to have to do some reworking on your own.  I'm just trying to give you the basic concept though.

Comment: I am not able to figure it out.. The scripts on Opera works fine, when I make an alert with the html, it gets me the html code even in Opera! The problem is that the code isn't appended. Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7amama/XCQQn/1/
and the same goes for flickr code

Comment: That's because you didn't even use my code... you're still using a query string and not the data parameter!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28179/discussion-between-cereallarceny-and-hamama)